# Write quoted value with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a large JSON data structure that I'm outputtng with Gson and I've hit a problem with one item. The JavaScript processing the JSON is expecting one of the values to be a function but I can't see a way to output an unquoted string.

For clarity, I have this member variable in my class:

```
private String myFunction = "$.foo.Bar";
```

Currently when I turn this into JSON I get:

```
"myFunction":"$.foo.Bar"
```

What I need is:

```
"myFunction":$.foo.Bar
```

As a bit of background the value of the myFunction variable is being passed to the jQuery `isFunction` function. When it's passed in as a string, obviously, it returns false.

I've tried replacing the `String` with a custom type and providing a serializer but I was then stuck with producing a `JsonPrimitive` element which didn't help.

Comment: Since that isn't valid JSON, attempting to use a JSON serialization library to generate it is probably going to prove difficult.

Comment: I suspected that might be an issue. I've just found this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/Uk14q5OtXmQ which discusses essentially the same issue. Anyone know if the security has been relaxed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with gson because that is not valid json format as defined in json.org.

Depending of the performance considerations, you can do something like:

```
String gson = "string containing somewhere in \"myFunction\":\"$.foo.Bar\" ...";
gson = gson.replace("\"myFunction\":\"$.foo.Bar\"", "\"myFunction\":$.foo.Bar");
```

Comment: I agree it's not valid JSON but I _really_ need output like this so any workaround would be greatly appreciated. I've literally hundreds of lines of data that is all valid JSON and then this one line that doesn't conform.

Comment: Comment updated, replace(str, str) should be fairly fast depending how much load that operation has

Comment: That was the only idea I'd come up with. I'm not so worried about the performance as I am about accidentally matching the wrong thing. Also the function `$.foo.Bar` can change so I'd a bit of regex to strip of the quotes. Certain food for thought though, thanks.

Comment: What about instead of writing $.foo.Bar you put a unique string that you are sure it wont appear and after you have the gson strin you run the replace over the special string with the real $.foo.Bar? You can safely be sure that replace is fast

Comment: Thanks for your help, string replacement is the option I've had to go for. I looked at every possible way of making Gson output what I wanted but it's impossible to override all the methods required in `JsonWriter` to produce invalid JSON and, as it's not an interface, I can't even provide my own lenient implementation.